# How do I use plotly events to filter data? event_register error message

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, ggplotly

I want to be able to double click on a category in a bar chart and filter all the data used in the graphs (currently 2) when I do so.

I know how to do it without plotly, but since the Specialties bar chart has many categories, I need plotly to have a zoom function.

I tried many different things but seem to never work. Right now, I have it set up as the same way it would work without plotly (the same as Joint KSA Grouping) inside a reactive val condition based on if detect click event.

It gives me an error that I need to register my event with event_register. I don't know where to put this piece of code and google shows nothing. All examples online do not help me since they do not involve filtering the data. Right now it seems that clicking is detected somehow by clicks on the specialties graph but because the event is not registered I can't use it in my reactive expression filtered_data().

I've tried event_register('Specialties', 'plotly_click') and put it in every location possible in the script with no success and always emit that error message that my thing isn't registered. I've tried putting different expressions as the first argument with no success.

```r
library('shiny')
library('dplyr')
library('readr')
library('ggplot2')
library('leaflet')
library('forcats')
library('plotly')


df <- read_csv('FinalData.csv')

df$EDIPI <- as.character(df$EDIPI)
df$BSOTYPE <- factor(as.character(df$BSOTYPE))
df$BSONAME <- factor(df$BSONAME)
df$PLATFORM <- factor(df$PLATFORM)
df$SPECIALTY <- factor(df$SPECIALTY)
df$SPECIALTY <- fct_explicit_na(df$SPECIALTY)
df$`Joint KSA Grouping` <- factor(df$`Joint KSA Grouping`,levels= c('CCCT', 'Non-CCCT_CCC', 'Non-CCCT_PriCare',
                                                                    'Non-CCCT_Dental', 'Non-CCCT_MentalHealth',
                                                                    'Non-CCCT_SupportCapability', 'Other'),
                                  ordered = TRUE)
df$`Joint KSA Grouping` <- fct_rev(df$`Joint KSA Grouping`)
df$`Joint KSA Grouping`<- fct_explicit_na(df$`Joint KSA Grouping`)

ui <- navbarPage('Navbar',
                 tabPanel('Tab1',
                          fluidRow(
                            column(width = 4,
                                   selectInput(inputId = 'training', 
                                               label = 'Training Filter',
                                               choices = sort(unique(df$TrainingFilter)),
                                               selected = sort(unique(df$TrainingFilter)),
                                               multiple = TRUE)
                            ),
                            column(width = 4,
                                   selectInput(inputId = 'emptyfilled', 
                                               label = 'Status Billet',
                                               choices = sort(unique(df$STATUS)),
                                               selected = sort(unique(df$STATUS)),
                                               multiple = TRUE)
                            ),
                            column(width = 4,
                                   radioButtons(inputId = 'specialty1', 
                                                label = 'Select Specialty',
                                                choices = c('All' = 'all', 'Manual Selection' = 'manual'),
                                                selected = "all"),
                                   conditionalPanel(
                                     condition = "input.specialty1 != 'all'",
                                     selectInput(inputId = 'specialty2',
                                                 label = 'Specialty',
                                                 multiple = TRUE,
                                                 choices = sort(unique(df$SPECIALTY)),
                                                 selected = 'Audiology')
                                   )
                            )
                          ),

                          fluidRow(
                            column(width = 12,
                                   hr()
                            )
                          ),
                          fluidRow(
                            column(width = 12,
                                   plotOutput(outputId = 'Map',
                                              hover = 'hoverMap',
                                              dblclick = 'clickMap')
                            )
                          ),

                          fluidRow(
                            column(width = 6,
                                   plotOutput(outputId = 'JointKSA',
                                              dblclick = 'clickJointKSA',
                                              click = 'unfilterJointKSA')

                            ),
                            column(width = 6,
                                   plotlyOutput(outputId = 'Specialties')
                            )
                          ),
                          fluidRow(
                            column(width = 6,
                                   plotOutput(outputId = 'Corps',
                                              dblclick = 'clickCorps')
                            ),
                            column(width = 6,
                                   plotOutput(outputId = 'BSO',
                                              dblclick = 'clickBSO')
                            )
                          )
                 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  filtered_JointKSA <- reactiveVal(0)
  filtered_Specialties <- reactiveVal(0)

  filtered_data <- reactive({
    req(input$training)
    data <- filter(df, TrainingFilter %in% input$training)

    req(input$emptyfilled)
    data <- filter(data, STATUS %in% input$emptyfilled)

    req(input$specialty1)
    if (input$specialty1 == 'manual') {

      req(input$specialty2)
      data <- filter(data, SPECIALTY %in% input$specialty2)
    }

    ###Joint KSA Grouping###

    if (filtered_JointKSA() != 0) {
      levelsJointKSA <- levels(data$`Joint KSA Grouping`)
      subsetJointKSA <- levelsJointKSA[levelsJointKSA %in% unique(data$`Joint KSA Grouping`)]
      itemsJointKSA <- subsetJointKSA[round(filtered_JointKSA())]
      data <- filter(data, `Joint KSA Grouping` %in% itemsJointKSA)
    }

    ###Joint KSA Grouping###

    ###SPECIALTY###

    if (filtered_Specialties() != 0) {

      levelsSpecialties <- levels(data$SPECIALTY)
      subsetSpecialties <- levelsSpecialties[levelsSpecialties %in% unique(data$SPECIALTY)]
      itemsSpecialties <- subsetSpecialties[round(filtered_Specialties())]
      data <- filter(data, SPECIALTY %in% itemsSpecialties)
    }    

    ###SPECIALTY###


    data <- filter(data, !is.na(EDIPI))
    data

  })

  ###Joint KSA Grouping###

  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$clickJointKSA, 
    handlerExpr = {filtered_JointKSA(input$clickJointKSA$y)}
  )

  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$unfilterJointKSA,
    handlerExpr = {filtered_JointKSA(0)}
  )

  ###Joint KSA Grouping###

  ###SPECIALTY###

  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = event_data("plotly_doubleclick", source = "Specialties"), 
    handlerExpr = {

      SpecialtiesClick = event_data("plotly_doubleclick", source = "Specialties")

      filtered_Specialties(SpecialtiesClick)}
  )

  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = event_data("plotly_click", source = "Specialties"),
    handlerExpr = {filtered_Specialties(0)}
  )  

  ###SPECIALTY###

  count_bso <- reactive({

    count(filtered_data(), BSONAME)

  })

  count_corps <- reactive({

    count(filtered_data(), SPECIALTYCORPS)

  })

  count_specialty <- reactive({

    filtered_data() %>%
      group_by(SPECIALTY) %>%
      summarize(Population = n()) 

  })

  count_jointksa <- reactive({

    filtered_data() %>%
      group_by(`Joint KSA Grouping`) %>%
      summarize(Population = n())



  })

  count_map <- reactive({

    filtered_data() %>%
      group_by(CITY_STATE, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE) %>%
      summarize(Population = n())

  })

  count_map_distance <- reactive({

    filtered_data() %>%
      filtered_data() %>%
      group_by(CITY_STATE, DISTANCE_GROUP, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE) %>%
      summarize(Population = n())

  })

  output$JointKSA <- renderPlot({

    colorcode1 <- colorRampPalette(c("#FFFFD4", "#FED98E", "#FE9929", "#D95F0E", "#993404"))

    JointKSA_colors <- setNames( colorcode1(length(levels(df$`Joint KSA Grouping`))),
                                 unique(df$`Joint KSA Grouping`))

    JointKSA_colors_subset <- JointKSA_colors[as.vector(count_jointksa()$`Joint KSA Grouping`)]

    bar <- ggplot(data = count_jointksa(), aes(x = `Joint KSA Grouping`, y = Population, fill = `Joint KSA Grouping`))+
      geom_bar(width = 1, stat = 'identity')+
      coord_flip()+
      theme(legend.position = "none",
            plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))+
      xlab('')+
      ggtitle('Joint KSA Grouping')+
      scale_fill_manual(values = JointKSA_colors_subset)

    bar
  })

  output$Specialties <- renderPlotly({

    colorcode2 <- colorRampPalette(c("#FFFFD4", "#FED98E", "#FE9929", "#D95F0E", "#993404"))

    Specialties_colors <- setNames( colorcode2(length(levels(df$SPECIALTY))),
                                    unique(df$SPECIALTY))

    Specialties_colors_subset <- Specialties_colors[as.vector(count_specialty()$SPECIALTY)]

    bar2 <- ggplot(data = count_specialty(), aes(x = SPECIALTY, y = Population, fill = SPECIALTY))+
      geom_bar(width = 1, stat = 'identity')+
      coord_flip()+
      theme(legend.position = "none",
            plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))+
      xlab('')+
      ggtitle('Specialties')+
      scale_fill_manual(values = Specialties_colors_subset)

    bar2

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

All I need to know is how to incorporate / set up single click and double click data with plotly objects so I can use them to filter data in my main reactive expression filtered_data().

Comment: [This](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html#shiny-plotly-inputs) will be of interest. Check `?event_data`

Comment: I've checked both of those sources already prior to posting the question. There is simply no reference online for what I want to do.

Comment: With "click on a category in a bar chart", are you referring to the legend items? Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54822671/r-plotly-how-to-observe-whether-a-trace-is-hidden-or-shown-through-legend-click) might be of interest.

Comment: My click/double click events work with the bar charts. My only problem is, converting my current syntax to plotly event syntax. I do not know where to put the code, how to structure it etc in terms of plotly and using event_data() or event_register()

Comment: I guess the main problem with your question is that 1. Your code isn't minimal and 2. not reproducible (no dummy data for `FinalData.csv`). Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The event_register is new so examples and documentation isn't super available so the best source of information for the version 4.9.0 would be the webinar on the RStudio Site [Accessing and Responding to Plotly Events in Shiny](https://resources.rstudio.com/webinars/accessing-and-responding-to-plotly-events-in-shiny-carson-sievert). Anyways, I think this should work to solve your event error:

```
output$Specialties <- renderPlotly({

colorcode2 <- colorRampPalette(c("#FFFFD4", "#FED98E", "#FE9929", "#D95F0E", "#993404"))

Specialties_colors <- setNames( colorcode2(length(levels(df$SPECIALTY))),
                                unique(df$SPECIALTY))

Specialties_colors_subset <- Specialties_colors[as.vector(count_specialty()$SPECIALTY)]

bar2 <- ggplot(data = count_specialty(), aes(x = SPECIALTY, y = Population, fill = SPECIALTY))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = 'identity')+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))+
  xlab('')+
  ggtitle('Specialties')+
  scale_fill_manual(values = Specialties_colors_subset)

bar2 %>% ggplotly(source = "Specialties") %>% event_register("plotly_click")

})
```

Pretty much explicitly convert it to plotly graph and then register the plotly click event for the Specialties graph.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later